# How can I redirect site to site use web.config?

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

Can I redirect all page of my site to new site?

```
<rule name="301 Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://take-car.ru{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

but its dont work

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="301 Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="omegaprokat.ru" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://take-car.ru{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```